# Perform change to all occurrences of multi-line selection

Tags: substitute

### Scenario

I would like to perform the following,

1. Visually select some text that spans multiple lines and occurs multiple times in the file: `V`
2. Yank to buffer: `y`
3. Perform substitute with text from buffer: (`:%s,<Ctrl-r> 0,new text,g`)

### Example

Given the following example:

```
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  version: 5.0
...
metadata:
  name: redis
```

I want to change all occurrences of metadata.

Output: `:%s,metadata:^M  name: redis,some other text,g`

Error: `E486: Pattern not found: metadata:^M  name: redis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vim-visual-multi`. Use multi line mode with `\\M`. Select all occurrences with `\\A` and do c to change.

Other people will tell you the vim way.

You can also use `%s/pattern\n nextline/something/` (or `^v<enter>` instead of \n  - would surely work ).

Comment: `Ctrl-V` + `Enter` doesn't work instead of `\n`: you end up with the same substitution that's described in the question.

Comment: So it is not clear why the original substitution didn't work. Unix vs windows file format?

Comment: No. When you yank a newline, it's stored in the yank register as a `NL` (regardless of the file format--I *think* this is how it's also stored in memory). But you cannot enter `NL` characters into the command-line: if you press `<Enter>` it runs the command; if you type `Ctrl-V Ctrl-J` it enters a `NUL`  instead (See `:help NL-used-for-Nul`), and if you insert the contents of a register with `<C-R>`, it converts the `NL` characters into `CR` characters. So when you search, instead of looking for multiple lines, it's looking for *single* lines that contain `CR` characters.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the characters used to represent newlines in a buffer are not the same as those needed to match a newline in a regular expression. As eyal kami suggests, you can fix this by manually replacing the Ctrl-M `^M` characters in your substitution with `\n`, or, perhaps cleaner, you could write a function to do both steps 2 and 3 for you:

```
function! MultiLineSubstitute() abort
  normal!gvy
  let expression = substitute(@0, "\<C-J>", '\\n', 'g')
  execute '%s,'.expression.','.input("Replacement: ")
endfunction

vnoremap <F1> :<C-U>call MultiLineSubstitute()<CR>
```

Note however that new lines are far from the only character that has a different meaning in a regular expression. You might want to look into the very nomagic atom (`:help /\V`) and the `escape()` function to work around this.